# What to do when object members of a class need access to each other's data?

Tags: c++, object, composition

I have a simple `Store` class that contains an `Inventory` object and a `CashRegister` object. In order to sell an item, the CashRegister object needs to access the Inventory object's methods; namely, those which return a particular item's price, quantity held in storage, etc. What's the best way to give the CashRegister object access to the Inventory object's methods?

Thank you.

Comment: Use [friendship](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/).

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is; usually accessor methods are public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the CashRegister object needs to access the Inventory object's methods

Why? The `CashRegister` can exist and operate perfectly without an `Inventory`. You can have a `CashRegister` in a theater or a cinema, not only in a `Store`. This part of the logic you're talking about should be part of the store.

```
class Store
{
   CashRegister register;
   Inventory I;
   void sellSomething(Item i)
   {
      //move logic inside the store
      //not in CashRegister
      int price = I.getPrice(i);
      register.addCash(price);
      I.removeItem(i);
   }
};
```

Comment: I replaced `Inventory.getPrice` by `I.getPrice` and `register.removeItem` by `I.removeItem` as it seemed more logical, feel free to revert.

Comment: I'd replace `I` with `inventory`, and `i` with `item`.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to store a reference to the `Inventory` object in the `CashRegister` object, and give the reference when constructing the `Store` object.

```
class Inventory { /* ... */ };

class CashRegister
{
public:
    CashRegister(Inventory &inventory)
        : inventory_(inventory)
    { }

    // ....

private:
    Inventory &inventory_;
};

class Store
{
public:
    Store()
        : cashregister_(inventory_)
    { }

    // ....

private:
    Inventory inventory_;
    CashRegister cashregister_;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Inventory {
  Currency price;
  uint64_t quantity;
  public:
    Currency get_price() { return price; }
    uint64_t get_quantity() { return quantity; }
};
```

Then your cash register can call the functions on an instance of `Inventory`.

But really, you should put a function on `Inventory` to reserve or deliver a certain number of objects if available -- a cash register does *not* need to know how many items are in stock, it only needs to know whether the current demand can be satisfied. For that matter, I'm not sure that an `Inventory` needs to know the price of an object -- if there's 10% off on Wednesday afternoons, then what business is that of the warehouse?

Answer (score 1):

Give objects responsibilities, don't just use them for clumping data.

The `Inventory` should know how to add and remove `Item`s. It may be that a transaction needs to take place. This assignment is a metaphor for a database.

@Luchian has the right idea but I would take it further.

You want the `Inventory` (database) to be able to process `Transaction`s, in this case one which is specialised to use a cash register.

The `Item` should be able to represent itself to the `Inventory`.

Look at the ideas of [Tell Don't Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask), and [Write No Getters](http://peripateticaxiom.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/tdd-mocks-and-design.html).